# How can make a device phone call by android using phoneGap and Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I need to make a call by android phoneGap application with  sencha touch button.
I have found an iphone plugin to make calls from phoneGap application. 
I has not found any plugins or anything for android.

Please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you want something better/deeper integrated than a simple `tel:12345` hyperlink? Could you please give more details? Like do you need to be able to customize the dialer, what plugin you found for iPhone, so people who know of similar ones for Android can answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a button which is created dynamically. Config is like  
  
    `{  
        xtype: 'button',  
        iconCls: 'phone1',  
        handler: function(buttonObject, event, options) {  
            //TODO: initiate call  
        }  
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Use this line to make a phone dialer to display

```
<a href="#"  rel="external" id="ext"  onclick="document.location='tel:123456'" > </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look in my Phonegap 1.5.0 Example index.html for Android I see this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
    <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap!</h1>
    <h2>this file is located at assets/www/index.html</h2>
    <div id="info">
        <h4>Platform: <span id="platform"> &nbsp;</span>,   Version: <span id="version">&nbsp;</span></h4>
        <h4>UUID: <span id="uuid"> &nbsp;</span>,   Name: <span id="name">&nbsp;</span></h4>
        <h4>Width: <span id="width"> &nbsp;</span>,   Height: <span id="height">&nbsp;
                   </span>, Color Depth: <span id="colorDepth"></span></h4>
     </div>
    <dl id="accel-data">
      <dt>X:</dt><dd id="x">&nbsp;</dd>
      <dt>Y:</dt><dd id="y">&nbsp;</dd>
      <dt>Z:</dt><dd id="z">&nbsp;</dd>
    </dl>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="toggleAccel();">Toggle Accelerometer</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="getLocation();">Get Location</a>
    <a href="tel:411" class="btn large">Call 411</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="beep();">Beep</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="vibrate();">Vibrate</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="show_pic();">Get a Picture</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="get_contacts();return false;">Get Phone's Contacts</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="check_network();return false;">Check Network</a>
    <dl>
    <dt>Compass Heading:</dt><dd id="h">Off</dd>
    </dl>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="toggleCompass();return false;">Toggle Compass</a>
    <div id="viewport" class="viewport" style="display: none;">
      <img style="width:60px;height:60px" id="test_img" src="" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice this line:  Call 411 When you click that button, you'll be calling 411. :)

Comment: I am able to use the tel:+phonenumber. However, this launches the phone dialer app of my android phone and i have to click on call. I have also included the CALL_PHONE permission in my manifest file. Is there some way to initiate call directly when this link is clicked rather than opening the phone dialer?